# SQL Count by equal columns Query

Tags: sql, count

I have this table:

```
subscriberID | date | segmentID | Counter
------------------------------------------
1            | 1.1  |    2      |    3 
1            | 2.1  |    4      |    2 
1            | 3.1  |    4      |    5 
2            | 1.1  |    1      |    12 
2            | 2.1  |    1      |    1
2            | 3.1  |    2      |    10 
3            | 1.1  |    2      |    4
```

I have to write SQL Query that does:

Get the top 3 most common segmentID's (by counter) for a given subscriberID.

can anyone help me with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select segmentID
from your_table
where subscriberID = 123
group by segmentID
order by sum(counter) desc
```

To get only 3 records you have to limit your result. Depending on your DB engine that could be `top 3` or `limit 3` or `rownum <= 3`.

Comment: I just changed it using `sum(counter)`. Not sure if that is what you want instead.